# How do I make an query parameter optional in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this regex:

```
^https?:path\?id=([a-zA-Z0-9._]+)&?.*&gl=([^&|\n|\t\s]+)&?.*$
```

the query parameter:

```
?id=([a-zA-Z0-9._]+)&?.*&gl=([^&|\n|\t\s]+)&?.*$
```

how do i make "gl" to be optional?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a job for regular expressions, using them for this purpose seems very brittle. What if the order of the parameters is reversed and you get `?gl=foo&id=bar`? You've tagged this JavaScript, where you can just use `new URL(str)` to actually parse the URL and validate its components directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^https?:path\?id=([^&]+)(?:.*?(?:&gl=([^&\s]+).*)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IBohg0/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `http` - a fixed `http` string
- `s?` - an optional `s` char
- `:path\?id=` - a fixed `:path?id=` string
- `([^&]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than a `&` char
- `(?:.*?(?:&gl=([^&\s]+).*)?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `(?:&gl=([^&\s]+).*)?` - an optional sequence of

    - `&gl=` - a fixed string
    - `([^&\s]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than whitespace and `&`
    - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks, it's do it.
I need it to be divided into 2 groups:
One for ״"id" and one more for "gl", how can I add this too?

Comment: @o.n There are two groups, get their values using your code.

Comment: i try in https://regex101.com/

Comment: @o.n So you can see the two green and orange highlighted texts there.

Comment: in  regex101.com - It only gave me one group of query parameters - only for the id,
I want there to be 2 groups - one for id and one for gl
What can i do for this?

Comment: @o.n There are two groups, one for `id` and one for `gl`. See [my regex demo again](https://regex101.com/r/IBohg0/1)

Comment: thanks.
I see that it requires that there be something between id and gl. How can I cancel it? (that gl could also be right after id)

Comment: @o.n I dwelt on the original problem and overlooked this. You need to use `^https?:path\?id=([^&]+)(?:.*?(?:&gl=([^&\s]+).*)?)?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/IBohg0/3.